# How to initialize base while hanging onto piece of what you're initializing with?

Tags: c#

I've been hitting this issue for a very long time and can never seem to find a good solution.

I know that the base class constructor must run before the child class constructor, ok.

But what if I need to initialize the base class with an object that itself needs another "part" that I also need to hang onto in the child that the base class should not know about? The way constructors are called seems to make this difficult if not impossible to achieve.

A simple example is something like this:

```
sealed class NeededByBase {
   readonly NeededByChild mNeededByChild;

   public NeededByBase(NeededByChild neededByChild) =>
      mNeededByChild = neededByChild;
}

sealed class NeededByChild {
}

class BaseClass {
   readonly NeededByBase mNeededByBase;

   protected BaseClass(NeededByBase neededByBase) =>
      mNeededByBase = neededByBase;
}

sealed class ChildClass : BaseClass {
   readonly NeededByChild mNeededByChild;

   // this doesn't work (static context)
   public ChildClass()
   : base(
      new NeededByBase(mNeededByChild = new NeededByChild())
   ) {
   }
}
```

Is there a way to do this without the base class knowing about the thing that the child class needs (that happens to be included in what the base class needs, but the base class doesn't know that).

I have the same or similar problem if I try to do this with virtual/abstract members, and also if I pass delegates.

I maybe could add a constructor to `ChildClass` that takes a `NeededByBase` but I'm in a situation where I require a default constructor in `ChildClass`.

Comment: I'm always surprised by the number of SO posters who hit this error message: `// this doesn't work`. It's always best to include the error message. What error are ypu seeing?

Comment: @Flydog57 you can't refer to the instance in the base constructor call (it's a static context)

Comment: Just for my understanding: In case someone calls the parameterless constructor for ChildClass, you want its mNeededByChild to be set to a "default"/simple new NeededByChild object, and that should then also be given to the base constructors. Am I at least somewhat close?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I might have something for you. This is a bit of a workaround. If you use :this() on a constructor you are able to call upon other constructors of that class. So what I did was to create a "normal" constructor, that takes a NeededByChild parameter which it can pass onto the parents base() constructor, whilst also using it to set its own attribute. Then I create a empty constructor that uses this() to call on that "filled" constructor. I hope that this can help you.

```
sealed class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
    readonly NeededByChild mNeededByChild;


    protected ChildClass():this(new NeededByChild())
    {

    }

    protected ChildClass(NeededByChild neededByChild):base(new NeededByBase(neededByChild))
    {
        mNeededByChild = neededByChild;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, I will try this out either later today or tomorrow

Comment: @DaveCousineau kk

Comment: this works great, thanks, I've been missing this for a long time

Comment: @DaveCousineau Glad to be of help ^^